# AngularJS chaining promises - need to do work before the next 'then'

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am working on a promise chain.  The first call is an $http call to check if a user exists, and then if it does, theres a bunch of .then() statements that run sequentially.

My question is this.. in that first call, i don't want to return the promise of the $http request because if the user doesn't exist, the results are just an empty array and the promise resolves, thus triggering the next action to look up information about the user.  I wrote the following code...

(see the part in comments about being the important part i'm asking about)

```
$scope.checkIfUserExists = function() {
      if (angular.isObject($scope.admin.Inductee.Contactor)) {

        var handleFault = function( fault ) {
          if (typeof(fault) === 'string') {
            switch (fault.toUpperCase()){
              case 'NODATA':
                // Go ahead an save
                $scope.pushInductee();
                break;

              case 'STATUS':
                // just get the 'duplicate records check' sign off of there
                // The save button is disabled by the critical error
                $scope.hideSave = false;
                break;

              case 'ASSIGNED':
                // just get the 'duplicate records check' sign off of there
                // The save button is disabled by the critical error
                $scope.hideSave = true;
                break;

              default:
                $log.error(fault);
                $location.path('/error/default');
            }
          } else {
            $log.error(fault);
            $location.path('/error/default');
          }
        };

        $scope.getMatchingIndData()
          .then($scope.procBusLogic)
          .then($scope.pushInductee) 
          .catch(handleFault);
      } 
    };


////HERE IS THE IMPORTANT PART I AM ASKING ABOUT
    $scope.getMatchingIndData = function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var locals = {};

  var checkUser = function(dupeJson){
    var checkUserDeferred = $q.defer();

    // abandoned promise replaced with my own
    sttiJoinDataFactory.checkIfUserExistsNurseleader(dupeJson)
      .then(function(results) {
        var data = results.data;
        if (angular.isArray(data) && data.length > 0){
          var highestMatch = data[0];

          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (parseInt(data[i].Score) > parseInt(highestMatch.Score)) {
              highestMatch = data[i];
            }
          }

          checkUserDeferred.resolve(highestMatch);

        } else {
          // Reject the 'overall' promise here
          // to effectively break the chain
          return deferred.reject('NODATA');
        }
      })
      .catch(function(fault) {
        // Any other failure should break the chain 
        // of http requests at this point
        return deferred.reject(fault);
      });

      return checkUserDeferred.promise;
    },
    loadindividual = function (highestMatch) {
      return $http stuff about the highestmatch
      // set data in locals
    },
    parallelLoadStatusAndInducteeData = function(individual) {
      return another $http promise based on the last then()
      // set data in locals
    },
    loadCeremonyData = function (inductees){
      return another $http promise based on the last call then()                           // set data in locals
    },
    reportProblems = function( fault ) {
      deferred.reject(fault);
    };

    checkUser($scope.generateDupJson())
    .then(loadindividual, reportProblems) 
    .then(parallelLoadStatusAndInducteeData, reportProblems)
    .then(loadCeremonyData, reportProblems)
    .then(function() { 
      deferred.resolve(locals); 
    })
    .catch( reportProblems );

  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Must I take into account the abandoned promise, since I really need to promise to resolve when the data comes back, and i need to reject it if there is NODATA.   This is handled in the calling function's chain.

Also, I'm aware of antipatterns here. I'm trying my best to not nest promises, maintain the chain, as well as handle exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have a few comments for you:

```
 ...
 // revert if and return immediately
 // to reduce indentation
 if (typeof(fault) !== 'string') {
   $log.error(fault);
   $location.path('/error/default');
   return;
 }
 switch (fault.toUpperCase()) {
 ...
```

You don't need deferred objects:

```
var checkUser = function(dupeJson){

  // this is not abandoned because we are returning it
  return sttiJoinDataFactory.checkIfUserExistsNurseleader(dupeJson)
  .then(function(results) {
    var data = results.data;
    if (!angular.isArray(data) || data.length <= 0) {
      return $q.reject('NODATA');
    }

    var highestMatch = data.reduce(function (highest, d) {
      return parseInt(d.Score) > parseInt(highest.Score) ? 
        d : highest;
    }, data[0]);

    return highestMatch;
  }); // you don't need catch here if you're gonna reject it again
}

...

checkUser(...)
  // loadIndividual will be called
  // after everything inside checkUser resolves
  // so you will have your highestMatch
  .then(loadIndividual)
  .then(parallelLoadStatusAndInducteeData)
  .then(loadCeremonyData)
  // you don't need to repeat reportProblems, just catch in the end
  // if anything rejects prior to this point
  // reportProblems will be called
  .catch(reportProblems)
  ...
```

Comment: I like this approach.  I am wondering though, how does $q.reject 'interact' with the $http promise from the sttiJoinDataFactory.  If the code is already in the .then() section, haven't we already technically resolved 'success' <- old way of doing it.

Comment: I implemented this, and as i thought, it continues down the chain after the reject, running loadindividual, parallelLoadStatusAndInducteeData, and loadCeremonyData

Comment: If you return nothing and chain a .then off the nothing, you will get an error, because undefined.then() is not actually a method.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship who is that directed at?  I'm returning a deferred promise, but orphaning the $http promise because its useless.

Comment: You are not orphaning it, you have semantic binding between your deferred object and $http promise.

Comment: Your first code block returns immediately, and returns nothing. Just making sure everyone's aware you can't chain a .then off of that.

Comment: As for your second comment (about continuing down when there's a rejection), what you describe is impossible so please check it again. If a promise fails and no one catches it, it won't continue down.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship It doesn't return a promise in the OP's code so that's OK.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship & mostruash sorry, i didn't clarify that the first code block is not a promise returning function.  Its called from another function that deals with the html side of an ng-click.  Also I want to clarify that what i've done works correctly... Just could it be done better.